# decent equalizer for 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, sound, realtek, equalizer

I am looking for decent equalizer for ubuntu 12.04. Recently, with 13.04 and 13.10 I have tried pulseaudio eq and other eq's. All of them were rubbish. Mainly because the output volume, because of them, decreased about 70% and equalizer it self (other than decreasing volume output) did nothing.
I have built in realtek audio chipset. I have not messed around with any sort of drivers, I have completely clean install of ubuntu.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have real patience then you can achieve with pulse audio but you need to a huge process
http://www.webupd8.org/2013/03/install-pulseaudio-with-built-in-system.html